# Cannot reach internet or lan

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, lan

I am runnung ubuntu 14.04 server on a Dell T300.  It has been running well for years.  Recently it stopped accessing the internet and I cannot access the files nor applications via the LAN.

It is connected to the network.  The connection information is:

```
Interface:  Ethernet (eth3)
hardware address: 00:10:18:EO:A6:54
Driver:  bnx2
Speed: 1000 Mb/s

IPv4
IP Address: 10.22.66.2
Broadcast address: 10.22.66.255
Sybnet Address: 255.255.255.0
Default Route 10.22.66.1
Primary DNS: 10.22.66.1
```

Also, I can ping google at 8.8.8.8 and receive a good response

The server will not connect to the internet nor can I access the files via the LAN.

I started Samba and it tells me that the job is already running.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "will not connect to the internet" - if you can successfully ping 8.8.8.8 then it is connecting to "the internet" (at least up to the network layer)

Comment: Hi Steeldriver,

Comment: Hi Steeldriver,   Thanks for the request to clarify.  I can ping the internet and receive a good response.   I have two issues:     1)  The browser I use cannot "see" the internet.   That is, when I try to access any website I receive a "Time  Out" error.   2) Another problem is that the Windows computers I have on my LAN cannot access the files on this server even though I point them to its IP address (10.22.66.12).  The applications I have running on Ubuntu are:  Apache, Samba, Ion Cube as well as two Linux apps. The only way I can access any data or applications is from  the server itself.

Comment: Is the address  10.22.66.1 an upstream dns server ? have you tried changing your dns-nameserver to 8.8.8.8 in /etc/network/interfaces ?

Comment: Hi Dan,  Being a novice tech I will try to answer your question.  The address 10.22.66.1 is a router.  All other computers can access the internet and printers on this LAN.  Is there an article that can explain to me how to get to and edit the file /etc/network/interfaces?